# How do I embed blog inside of codeigniter application

Tags: php, apache, codeigniter-3

I would like to embed myawesomeblog.com inside of a codeigniter application. Essentially, what I would like to see is when a user goes to my site (www.myexample.com) and clicks on blog they will be redirected to (www.myexample.com/blog) instead of myawesomeblog.com. I would like to keep the users location bar at www.myexample.com/blog.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, you have your app and your blog on different domains?

You could try reverse proxy with Apache. No CI code is needed.

On your apache configuration:

```
ProxyPass /blog/ http://myawesomeblog.com/
ProxyPassReverse /blog/ http://myawesomeblog.com/
```

Comment: This is more inline with what I was thinking. This works at the http configuration level. I need something that can work with .htaccess. Is there something that would work with .htaccess?